# Component files not importing in webpack react project?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've set up a pretty simple React app and I can't get any of my components to import to index.js. My index.js, which contains the definition of my main `<App />` class, works fine, and has this line for example:

```
import { IntroductionPage } from './Components/IntroductionPage.js';
```

With a nice definition of the IntroductionPage component exported from IntroductionPage.js, what I'm getting is an error about IntroductionPage being undefined in index.js:

```
React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `App`.
    in App
```

I'm not sure what to change-- I can see console.log output from IntroductionPage.js, so it is getting run/compiled. If I move the IntroductionPage component definition into index.js, everything works great. Somehow I'm losing it in the import/export step.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: Can you show me the code of your IntroductionPage.js? Could you try to remove the brackets from the import with only the following?
import IntroductionPage from './Components/IntroductionPage.js';

Comment: We have a winner....removing the brackets fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: You should make that comment into an answer.

Comment: Sure, will do now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to remove the brackets from the import with only the following code:

```
import IntroductionPage from './Components/IntroductionPage.js';
```

Check out the [import docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) on MDN-- if you're using `export default` for your class, you don't want brackets when you import it like this.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to give more explanation on import and export scenarios that work in react.

This is a **default import**:

```
// App.js
import IntroductionPage from './IntroductionPage'
```

It only works if `IntroductionPage` contains a **default export**:

```
// IntroductionPage.js
export default 50
```

In this case it doesn’t matter what name you assign to it when importing:

```
// App.js
import IntroductionPage from './IntroductionPage'
import MySample from './IntroductionPage'
import Test from './IntroductionPage'
```

Because it will always resolve to whatever is the **default export** of `IntroductionPage`.

---

This is a **named import** called `IntroductionPage`:

```
import { IntroductionPage } from './IntroductionPage'
```

It only works if `IntroductionPage` contains a **named export** called `IntroductionPage`:

```
export const IntroductionPage = 52
```

In this case the name matters because you’re importing **a specific thing by its export name**:

```
// App.js
import { IntroductionPage } from './IntroductionPage'
import { mySample } from './IntroductionPage' // Doesn't work!
import { Test} from './IntroductionPage' // Doesn't work!
```

To make these work, you would add a **corresponding named export** to `IntroductionPage`:

```
// IntroductionPage.js
export const IntroductionPage = 50
export const mySample = 51
export const Test= 52
```

A module can only have **one default export**, but **as many named exports as you like** (zero, one, or many). You can import them together:

```
// App.js
import IntroductionPage, { mySample, Test } from './IntroductionPage'
```

Here, we import the default export as IntroductionPage, and named exports called mySample and Test, respectively.

```
// IntroductionPage.js
export default 50
export const mySample= 51
export const Test= 52
```

We can also assign them all different names when importing:

```
// App.js
import X, { mySample as myTest, Test as myTest2} from './IntroductionPage'
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try this `package.json` and install the boilerplate of react.
package.json file is here:

```
    {
  "name": "bp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

and then go to cmd and wrtie these commands one by one:

```
> npm install
> npm install -g create-react-app
> create-react-app my-app
> 
> cd my-app npm start
```

Comment: I understand the idea you have in mind, resetting all my configuration to eliminate the possibility of it being some arcane configuration mistake, but ultimately I needed a better solution than "start over." Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way!